# Ember.js - formdata returns null in ember ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js, ember-cli

I have encountered an issue with formdata in ember ajax call.when im trying to send formdata with ajax request it returns null value for formdata.

heres my formdata

```
    var formData = new FormData();  
    formData.append('url', "http://emberjs.com");
    formData.append('urlType',2);
```

and ajax call

```
this.ajax(url, 'POST', {           
      data: formData,
      headers: {
           'Content-Type': false,
           'processData': false               
      }
 });
```

Comment: Can you have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8244082/1784876) ?

Comment: @A.OzanEkici I have tried with jquery ajax but theres some problem with authentication.

Comment: Do you have the access to the backend? Can you inspect the backend log?

Comment: @LiXinyang the network itself it shows "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect." since theresnt any values in formdata.